# Multiple subs and using the ScreenUpdating property

Tags: excel, vba

My project has 50 subroutines and a main subroutine that calls all of them.

I'm trying to keep my code as quick, clean and effective as possible, so should I add the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False/True` snippet to the beginning and end of *each individual sub*, or would it have the same effect if I just add it to the main sub?

```
Sub CallAllMacros()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call macro1
Call macro2
...
Call macro50
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End sub
```

Comment: Just the main sub

Comment: Do you call the single routines also stand alone or only as part of `CallAllMacros`?

Comment: @FunThomas only as part of `CallAllMacros`! I assume in that case it's enough to add it to that sub?

Comment: Yes, in that case just don't put it into the subroutines.

Comment: If you do ever need it in the called subs, don't just reset `screenupdating` to true at the end of each one. Check the value when the sub is called and only reset it if that was true. Otherwise your main sub will end up turning updating on and off 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it into main sub. So, only 2 lines are required.

1. At the very beginning: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
2. At the end : Application.ScreenUpdating = True